# How to generate list of buttons from a list of items in a table with entityframework and wpf without MVVM?

Tags: wpf

I have a table [Foods] with list of my foods. I want to generate buttons for each of the food in the table with the name of the food. How can i do this in WPF application. Consider that i use Entity Framework 6x but not MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `ItemsControl` with an `ItemTemplate` and sets its `ItemsSource` to an `IEnumerable<Food>` that you get from Entity Framework, e.g.:

```
FoodContext _context = new FoodContext();
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ic.ItemsSource = _context.Books.ToList();
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="ic">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Please refer to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/databinding/wpf) for more information.